# Automatic parameter selection in SEAL

Tags: seal

The [SEAL library (v 2.1.3)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/simple-encrypted-arithmetic-library/#!download) offers an automatic parameter selection tool to help choose the optimal parameter values for a given evaluation function of the ciphertexts.

The current version of SEAL, however, only supports the Integer Encoder. In other words, it only supports cases where the inputs are encryptions of integers.

Is there a way to extend automatic parameter selection tool in SEAL to cover the FractionalEncoder? In other words, is there a way to adapt the automatic parameter selection tool to handle cases where the inputs to the evaluation function are rational numbers?

Comment: The parameter selector tool is outdated and is not being developed further. It indeed does not work with FractionalEncoder and there is no obvious way to make it work. There are many new ideas for automated parameter selection and optimization being discussed in the http://HomomorphicEncryption.org community and standardization workshops; these will eventually replace the old parameter selection tool in SEAL.